# Do something on hover if sibling element hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list, which all include a link and an image each. Some of the images have a class which others do not.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>link 1</a>
    <img src="http://foo.com/" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>link 2</a>
    <img src="http://foo.com/" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>link 3</a>
    <img src="http://foo.com/" class="myClass" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to do something on hover of those links, but only if the associated image has that class.

This is what I'm currently trying:

```
$('ul li a').hover(
    function() {
        if ($(this).siblings('img').hasClass('.myClass')) {
                console.log('it has the class');
        }
});
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not pass `.` to the `hasClass` method, remove it.

```
if ($(this).siblings('img').hasClass('myClass')) {
```

In case that classes are not added/removed dynamically, you can also use `.filter()` method:

```
$('ul li a').filter(function() {
    // return $(this).siblings('img').hasClass('myClass');
    return this.nextElementSibling.className.indexOf('myClass') > -1;
}).hover(function(){
    // ...
});
```

Or `+ adjacent selector`.